# unexpected not defined error in javascript

Tags: php, jquery

I have page in which there's a function which  calls a function from js file.

the code which calls function in js file:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var qc = qc_chat;
window.onload = function()
{
qc.setup('<?php echo $p; ?>');
}
</script>
```

I am including qc.js file using this code:

```
function doThat() {
    $.ajax({
        url:    'http://www.example.com',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'adrs='+getHost( document.domain ),
        dataType:   'jsonp',
        jsonp:  false,
        jsonpCallback: 'methodCallback',
        success: function( data ) {
            if( data.message == "yes" ) {

            } else {

        $.getScript("qc.js"); //files m including using this ajax
    $.getScript("tools.js");  //files m including using this ajax
            }
        }, 
        error: function( error ) {
            console.log( error ); 
        }
    });
}
```

and i am calling `doThat()` using `<body onload="doThat();">`

but i am getting the error in console `Uncaught ReferenceError: qc_chat is not defined`

Thanks

Comment: Where is `qc_chat` defined. if it is not defined at all you will get this error.

Comment: Yes, please show where it *is defined*. It is not in your code.

Comment: Is `qc_chat` by any chance defined inside `qc.js`?

Comment: It's because you do this: `var qc = qc_chat;`
That won't work because it doesn't know what to put into the variable `qc`.

Comment: You have defined `qc`, but **not** `qc_chat`

Comment: The `onLoad` events are going to fire before any of the async calls finish...

Comment: if qc_chat is defined in qc.js, and qc.js is brought int via ajax. the onload function will be called before the ajax call is finished. so the function will not be available at that time. does that sound right?

Comment: You can't use PHP in an external JS file

Comment: Why are you going around your back to get to your elbow? I mean, why are you not just loading the js in the `<head>`?

Comment: @scrowler well, technically you can, it just isn't advisable.

Comment: qc_chat is defined in qc.js and it works if i directly load files in head. but i wnat to load it thru that

Answer (score 3):

Since `$.getScript` is asynchronous, anything that depends on the script it loads must be done in its callback function. So it should be:

```
$.getScript('qc.js', function() {
    qc_chat.setup('<?php echo $p; ?>');
});
```

Comment: may be `<body onload="doThat('<?php echo $p; ?>');">` and `function doThat(_p) {` and `qc_chat.setup(_p)` since the other code is a .js file

Comment: error is not shwoing but my code is also not working...which is dependent on that files. :(

Comment: If it's not getting an error, then it's running the function. I can't explain why it's not doing what you expect. Use the JS debugger, set a breakpoint on the `qc_chat.setup` line and see what's happening.

Comment: @Barmar nohting happend...i think i need to load the `doThat()` before the page loads so that it load qc.js before the page loads completey? how to do that ?

Comment: That seems unlikely. But you can but the call do `doThat()` in a `<script>` tag in the `<head>` instead of the `onload` attribute, and it will run before the body loads. But since it uses AJAX, `qc.js` will still not be loaded until later.

Comment: @Barmar u r right.. can we do that the same function done by abive jsonp script using curl or anything else ..or can i update the database using return value from jsonp script

Comment: I don't know what that jsonp script does. And what does that have to do with calling QC functions on the client. What is QC?

Comment: @Barmar  above jsonp script calls to php file on another server and get response back from it...can i do it using php curl ?? leave the qc for now.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. It's called a PHP proxy. See http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/ for a popular script. I don't understand what it has to do with this question, which is about the undefined function `qc_chat`.

Comment: @Barmar let me explian you...i am doing the licensing for the script....Qc js is the file which makes the app working..

Comment: I'm totally lost, I give up on this one. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When I can't to edit the place where some modules connects, I use this snippet:

```
var waitForqcchat = setInterval(function(){
  if(typeof qcchat != 'undefined'){
    clearInterval(waitForqcchat);
    //here I sure, that module connected
    qcchat.setup('<?=$p?>');
  }
}, 200);
```

*You should also write a logic to limit waiting if qcchat can never to be connected*

Comment: It works, but it's an incredible kludge. Learn to use callback functions properly.

Comment: Agree, this only for cases, when I can't modify/detect the place where  script connected. Place like `$.getScript('qc.js')`